# Is it possible to select a specific worker for a specific task in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, cluster-computing, mesos

Actual requirement is like i have devices which is accessible through specific machines only, so is it possible that to assign a task which involved communication to a specific device to a worker from which that device is accessible ?

Assume that there is spark cluster with master and workers. Workers are machines which has access to specific devices, master has no access to those devices.

I gone through documentions and got to know that it is possible through using mesos cluster manager but not able to find something depicts that how exactly this can be done , any reference for that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> [`spark.mesos.constraints`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html) — Attribute based constraints on mesos resource offers. By default, all resource offers will be accepted. This setting applies only to executors. Refer to [Mesos Attributes & Resources](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/attributes-resources/) for more information on attributes.
>   Scalar constraints are matched with "less than equal" semantics i.e. value in the constraint must be less than or equal to the value in the resource offer.
>   Range constraints are matched with "contains" semantics i.e. value in the constraint must be within the resource offer's value.
>   Set constraints are matched with "subset of" semantics i.e. value in the constraint must be a subset of the resource offer's value.
>   Text constraints are matched with "equality" semantics i.e. value in the constraint must be exactly equal to the resource offer's value.
>   In case there is no value present as a part of the constraint any offer with the corresponding attribute will be accepted (without value check).

Comment: Sorry to raise the dead on this one -- It looks like Spark deprecated fine grained mesos support in 2.0.0 in favor of "Dynamic Allocation".   This isn't the same as the use case above is certainly valid.  Would you happen to know, @janisz, if there's a path forward in Spark 3.3+?

Comment: I have not tested this but according to docs it should work